# SSD not recognized in BIOS anymore

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I already asked a question here a few days ago regarding problems during startup of my freshly installed Windows 8.1 on my new Samsung Evo 850.
Now, after a sudden bluescreen, the SSD is not recognized by BIOS anymore. I checked the SATA and power cable, but everything seems to be good. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the SSD has failed and died, hence it not being seen in BIOS - check it in another system to verify if you can. As with various other components, if an SSD survives the first month of use the chances are it will continue working until it dies of natural wear. Sadly it looks like yours didn't make it...

Comment: I am not able to check it at the moment. But I checked that the cables are fine by plugging in my HDD.

Comment: After plugging the SSD back in, it is recognized again. But still that of cause doesn't give me a good feeling...

Comment: That's a relief. Are you using locking SATA connectors? Always a good idea. If I were you I'd download the Samsung Magician software which will let you check the drive's health and run firmware updates if available - http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html

Comment: Both good ideas. I will do that.

Comment: The health is "good" is that the best result or did it already take damage? Also AHCI seems to be disabled. Is it save to simply turn it on?

Comment: Yes it should be safe to enable AHCI but you may need to restore your previous setting if Windows fails to start properly. If the health status is good then go ahead and use it, if it survives a month without any more problems you should be fine. Don't put anything critical on it without having a backup though. Do try some locking connectors if you can and possibly secure the power connector with some adhesive tape if it doesn't have a latch or feels at all loose.

Comment: I just got a BSOD again and now it's again gone. I don't get what the problem is...

Comment: Maybe it really is the cable since it works again after some tries and port switching. But the PC is standing absolutely still, so why the sudden bluescreens?

Comment: Do you have similar issues when using a standard hard drive or is it just the SSD causing issues?

Comment: I bought the SSD because my old HDD had an extremely low health status. It failed spinning up sometimes. But I won't rule out that this was the cables fault.

Comment: Sounds possible, change your SATA data cable and see how it goes and  - don't forget to report back with your findings too ;-)

Comment: Since I switched to AHCI (using safe mode) I didn't experience any errors. But I also have a locking SATA connector now. I guess one of these have fixed it.